# Can you be 1/12th Cherokee?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, fractions

I was watching an old *Daily Show* clip and [someone self-identified as "one twelfth Cherokee"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loK2DRBnk24#t=4m31s). It sounded peculiar, as people usually state they're "$1/16$th", or generally $1/2^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Obviously you could also be some summation of same to achieve $3/32$nds, etc., but will an irreducible fraction with the numerator $1$ always need a power-of-two denominator? More generally does it always require a power-of-two denominator?

Assumptions (as per comments):

1. Nobody can trace their lineage infinitely
2. Incest is OK, including transgenerational, but someone can't be their *own* parent.

Comment: With enough incest you can be any rational you like.

Comment: @AlecTeal does incest break the 50-50 genetic contribution from maternal and paternal lineage? I think there could be some strange results from crossover and meiosis, but would have to think about it and/or ask my friends in meiosis labs.

Comment: @NickT lets not over-complicate it. Let's suppose your dad and your sister have a baby, your mother is of race A and your father is of race B, that means your sister is 50:50 AB, their child would get 50% from mother, 50% from father, that is 75% B and 25% A, so this baby would be 3/4ths B. It'd be quite literally 3/4 your dad, and 1/4 your mother. (lets not be weird and be like "subtracting a quarter of a chromosome because it might be a boy" that'd lead to weird ones)

Comment: Actually I see your point @NickT you can't express 1/12 as p/2^n for some n.

Comment: If your otherwise non-Cherokee grandmother went back in time, found her Cherokee grandfather, and had a baby (her father) with him, then she would be $\frac13$ Cherokee and you would be $\frac1{12}$ Cherokee. That's probably what happened.

Comment: @GregMartin can it be done without time travle?

Comment: @GregMartin does it just require multigenerational incest or of the less-plausible, strictly acausal "one's own grandfather"-type?

Comment: Inecst of any type doesn't change the fact that you're still getting $\frac1{2^k}$ of your lineage from each of your level-$k$ ancestors; regardless of whether some of your ancestors are to be counted with multiplicity or at multiple levels, their contribution to your lineage is still some dyadic fraction (power of $2$ denominator). You're not going to get $\frac1{12}$ that way.

Comment: Chuck Norris is 1/12 Cherokee.

Comment: Okay, see my answer, finite strings of zeros and ones FTW!

Comment: If anyone cares -.- Damn not getting there first.

Comment: He could have been a cannibal, and eaten $\frac 1{11}$ of a Cherokee...just depends on your model...

Comment: I guess someone did the arithmetic $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{4 + 8} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: Or he could spend 1 month a year as a Cherokee.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Chuck Norris is $2^\sqrt{2}$ Cherokee.

Comment: Maybe if you are 3/32th Cherokee, and have 1/9th of your body amputated after an accident...

Comment: @AsafKaragila chucknorrisfacts.com got [that one](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/node/1812) wrong.

Comment: @Jeppe: No, it's just that since the fact was posted, Chuck Norris ate other things and the relative decomposition of Chuck Norris into "Cherokee" and "Other stuff" has changed.

Comment: Chuck Norris is $\tfrac{-1}{12}$ cherokee. Why? Cherokee are pretty tough guys, so it's reasonable to assume they're actually descended from Chuck Norris. Since Chuck Norris doesn't care about ratio, his ethnicity is in fact defined by the sum of all his descendants, and that'd be infinite because that tribe won't go extinct with Chuck Norris as its ancestor, will it! So actually Chuck Norris's is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$ Cherokee, which [as we all know sums up to $\tfrac{-1}{12}$!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Ramanujan_summation)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Good argument, but you forget that Chuck Norris has absolute power, so $-\frac1{12}$ becomes $\frac1{12}$. :-)

Comment: I never thought I'd come on to MSE and find a question which included 'Incest is OK'.

Comment: If there were a [chimeric human of two distinct biological fathers](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131113213735AAKQHbo), could the resultant offspring possibly be considered to have 1/3 of a specified genetic origin... thus allowing for a grandchild to be 1/12th?

Comment: The short answer: 12 has a factor of 1/3 and thus cannot be produced by combining powers of 1/2.

Comment: Incest seems to resolve the problem, but that's quite disputable. Say Adam is Cherokee and he has a son Jake with Jane and a daughter Belinda with Brenda. Then Jake and Belinda have a child, Caroline. Is Caroline 1/3 Cherokee, because Adam is one of 3 her grandparents? Or is she 1/2 Cherokee, because she inherits Adam's genes twice of four paths?

Comment: Yes, as long as one of your grandparents has 3 parents....

http://news.nationalpost.com/2014/02/10/vancouver-baby-becomes-first-person-to-have-three-parents-named-on-birth-certificate-in-b-c/

Comment: Perhaps by 1/12th the person meant *about* 1/12. If you have one parent at 1/16 and the other at 1/8, you will be 9/96. 8/96 = 1/12. I suspect this is a common thing to say in light of this.

Comment: @fredsbend sorry to say, but 9/96 is nearer 1/10th than 1/12th, and 1/11th is the nearest you can get with a `1` in the numerator.

Comment: @Alexander That may be true, but the common person is not very good with fractions. I was merely posing the likelihood that a person claiming to be a 1/12 of some heritage was likely rounding. Considering having one parent at 1/16 and another at 1/8 are both very common factors, this seems possible.

Comment: @fredsbend in that case it's probably as azimut suggests above

Answer (score 175, accepted):

This depends on the model. Instead of arguing that we have only $46$ chromosomes and cross-overs or whatever the mechanism is called are not *that* common, let us assume a continuous model.
That is, a priori, everybody can be $\alpha$ Cherokee for any $\alpha\in[0,1]$ and the rules are as follows

- Everybody has exactly two parents.
- If the parents have Cherokee coefficients $\alpha_m, \alpha_f$, then the child has $\alpha=\frac{\alpha_m+\alpha_f}2$
- In a sufficiently large but finite number of generations ago, people had $\alpha\in\{0,1\}$

It follows by induction, that $\alpha$ can always be expressed as $\alpha=\frac{k}{2^n}$ with $k,n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $0\le k\le 2^n$. Consequently $\alpha=\frac1{12}$ is not possible exactly (though for example $\frac{85}{1024}\approx\frac1{12}$ would be possible).
It doesn't matter if there is any type of inbreeding taking place anywhere in the tree (or then not-tree) of ancestors.
The only way to obtain $\alpha$ not of this form would involve time-travel and genealogical paradoxes: If you travel back in time and paradoxically become your own grandparent and one of the other three grandparents is $\frac14$-Cherokee and the others are $0$-Cherokee, you end up as a solution to $\alpha=\frac{\frac14+\alpha}4$, i.e. $\alpha=\frac1{12}$.

Comment: Any genealogy solution that requires time travel is a good solution.

Comment: @Hagen: Why not some inbreeding?

Comment: @DeadMG Inbreeding doesn't do the trick, because there's no difference between having one person appear multiple times in a family tree and having many people with the same coefficient each appear once in the tree. For instance, if your grandfathers are the same person, and he has $\alpha=1/4$ with both grandmothers having $\alpha=0$, that's equivalent to having no inbreeding and having both grandfathers' $\alpha=1/4$, with your $\alpha=1/8$ in both cases. The grandfather appearing twice contributes fully half of your Cherokeeness, not a third.

Comment: Wait, didn't ["I'm My Own Grandpa"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw) show you could be your own grandpa *without* the need for time travel?

Comment: @bof: simply a representation of how humans chose to define race. Yes, *if* the US government had showed up and declared certain people at a certain time to be 2/3 Cherokee and 1/3 Navajo, *then* it would be easy to be 1/12 Cherokee. They did not do that.

Comment: @bof Yeah, that is all somewhat convoluted and as I said part of the underlying assumptions. Sufficiently many generations ago, there was just some slime in the Ocean ... If we go ahead (and perhaps also drop the idea of race) and simply speak  about alleles leading to some phenotype, then these are probably not even distributed over all 23 pairs of chromosomes. Then (ignoring mutations) one can have only a certain fraction, always a multiple of some fixed $\frac1N$ with $N<46$, of the corresponding allels. Problem number one is to explain, which of these make "Cherokee-ness".

Comment: You receive 50% of your DNA from each parent, but that doesn't necessarily mean you get 25% from each grandparent. There is no way to gauge *which* 50% of a parent's DNA you received, so you could in principle share up to 50% of your DNA with one grandparent and 0% with their spouse. If this is the case, then of course we can have an individual be any proportion Cherokee less than 50% if a grandparent is 100% Cherokee.

Comment: AFAIK biologists are reasonably in consensus that you can't rigorously define/measure race by DNA. Nevertheless, there's some simple arithmetic behind legal and social definitions of race, and it typically behaves as Hagen modelled it. The fact that it makes no sense in terms of DNA or any other physical process is irrelevant :-) It's biologically possible, of course, that the twelfth-Cherokee person in the question is saying so on the basis of DNA sequencing that reveals they have 1 in 12 of somebody's list of "characteristic" Cherokee genetic markers. If such a list exists or is invented.

Comment: The only way I see that time travel or inbreeding makes it possible is if you count the time traveler or inbreeder only once even though they occur multiple times on the family tree. But he would still contribute his genes to the result twice, so I don't think that counting him only once would be accurate.

Comment: @SteveJessop Needed to say: There's re-combination going on, so you receive 25% of each of your grandpa's DNA. (I'm not 100% sure on this, and a biologist should rather confirm my statement. Still, this is how I understood re-combinations.

Comment: @yo': more accurate would be to say that where differences exist, you have approximately a 25% chance of getting each of your grandparents' gene variants. It doesn't follow that you get exactly 25% of a hypothetical list of 100 "Cherokee genes", any more than if you toss 100 coins you get exactly 50 heads. Recombination "just" means that you can get two genes from different grandparents even if the genes are on the same chromosome -- without it whole chromosomes would be passed on unchanged other than by mutation.

Comment: @SteveJessop I know. At the same time, it's needed to say that the coins are not $100$ but rather something like $40000$, so the mean deviation is $\sim200 = 0.5%$. I just wanted to point out that it's not $23$. On the other hand, this means that you can get very precisely $1/12$ of Cherokee genes even with 2 or 3 generations considered. However, this model is far from what people have in mind with "I'm $1/8$th Cherokee", right?

Comment: RE percentages of DNA: Barring errors in the process of genetic transmission, you will get exactly 50% of your DNA from your mother and 50% from your father, 25% from each grandparent, etc. Yes, it's true that we can't say exactly which 50%, 25%, etc. Whether that's relevant to the question depends on how we define "Cherokeeness". I think the conventional definition is that it's percentage of total genetic material, period. If you defined it in terms of physical characteristics, like skin tone, shape of the nose, etc, then the question becomes much more complex ... and probably impossible ...

Comment: ... to define rigorously and definitively. Like if a white person and a black person have a baby, USUALLY the baby has an intermediate skin tone, but it sometimes happens that the baby looks simply white or simply black. Depending on exactly how you defined Cherokeeness, it may be that in that sense, any percentage would be possible. (Well, I guess the denominator would have to divide into the number of relevant chromosomes times a power of 2.)

Comment: @Jay: exactly. I've assumed without stating, that these hypothetical genetic markers for Cherokee are such a small proportion of the human genome that we can treat it as independent coin tosses at approximately 50%, rather than working out the actual dependence between them. So if one of your grandparents has all the Cherokee markers (100% Cherokee) and the other grandparents have none of them (0% Cherokee), then you *could* be anywhere in between but expected value is 25% of them. If Cherokee were 90% genetically distinct from the rest of homo sapiens we couldn't do that :-)

Comment: ... so when yo' says " the coins are not 100 but rather something like 40000", it seems utterly implausible to me that there are 40k genes for which characteristic Cherokee variants exist, since that's all the genes and would arguably make Cherokee even more genetically distinct from the rest of homo sapiens than are (for example) fungi ;-)

Comment: @Jay The reason time travel makes it possible is that if someone is their _own_ ancestor, their Cherokeeness now depends on itself ($\alpha$ is a function of $\alpha$). It's not that you double-count them in the family tree (as you mention, that doesn't change anything).

Comment: @cpast Ah, I misread that before. I was thinking the poster was saying that, e.g. your FATHER goes back in time and also becomes your great-grandfather. But if you yourself go back in time and become your own grandfather, you're right, I see it now, instead of x=(p1+p2)/2 it becomes x=(p1+x)/2, etc. Which means that if your father did go back in time and become HIS own grandfather, that could also give non-binary denominators. So I retract my previous statement. I was wrong. I hang my head in shame.

Comment: @MichaelCromer the law of large numbers (and the size of the human genome *is* large) makes significant deviations from the 2^-n rule rather unlikely until we reach pretty large n. :)

Comment: So because of the fuzziness and randomness of genetics, maybe we actually could say that exact ratios are possible - though extremely unlikely - if the total number of "coefficients" is divisible by the fraction we are interested. But the fatal weakness of the answer is - like @Hagen himself admitted in the comments -  that there is this mysterious assumption of the existence of criteria for for determining binary Cherokeeness of the coefficients. How the heck can we distinguish those in a random offspring? Chemically Cherokee coefficients and non-Cherokee coefficients can be identical.

Comment: @Keavon: Technically, the protagonist of that song is his own *step*-grandfather, not his own biological grandfather.

Comment: It's uncanny that no one mentioned this before. But if you are your own grandfather then you are likely to be [missing the Delta brainwave](http://theinfosphere.org/Delta_brainwave). It might be useful if flying space brains attack the earth, but it might also be less useful in other aspects.

Comment: Recent news. Three parent baby? http://news.yahoo.com/three-people-baby-185550160--politics.html

Answer (score 36):

No, **nobody can be $1/12th$ Cherokee**.

I'll prove a stronger statement:

> *For any natural $p$ and $q$, one can't be a $p/q$ Cherokee if $p$ **is not** divisible by $3$, and $q$ **is** divisible by $3$*.

First, the statement that a person can be only "*rational* number of a Cherokee" can be easily proven - I won't waste space for the proof here.

Now, let's suppose a person was such $p/q$ Cherokee, then, supposing that his/hers parents were $p_1/q_1$ and $p_2/q_2$ Cherokee (fractions are reduced to their minimal form), the following would be valid

$$p/q = (p_1/q_1 + p_2/q_2)/2$$

or

$$2\times p\times q_1\times q_2=q\times (p_1\times q_2+p_2\times q_1)$$

Since $q$ is divisible by $3$, and  $p$ is not divisible by $3$, this means that one of $q_1$ and $q_2$ must be divisible by $3$. In other words, one of the parents have the same property as the original person.

And than you can go ad infinitum - but since the oldest ancestor can be either 100% or 0% Cherokee, and that person does not satisfy the property of being "$p/q$ Cherokee if $p$ is not divisible by $3$, and q is divisible by $3$", this is a *contradiction*.

This means nobody can be $1/12th$ Cherokee.

Comment: You're making too many assumptions.  Two things interfere with your model.  1) You don't have to go back too many generations before some overlap in relatives will occur.  2nd or 3rd cousin marriages used to be semi-frequent, and don't even cross that "taboo" threshold.  2) Generations aren't static.  One side of one's family could have habitually married and reproduced young, to include 5 or 6 generations in a century, while others in the family tree may have waited until late in life, creating only 2 or 3 generations in the same timeframe.

Comment: @Random Not at all, I don't make any assumption of that kind...

Comment: In it's simplest form, here's how it could work going back to the great-great grandparents generation.  Brothers Don, Dan, David & Duke.  They marry four girls, Darla, Destiny, Delilah, & Daisy (unrelated).  Don & Darla have a boy, Carl.  Dan & Destiny have a boy, Cameron.  David & Delilah have a girl, Cathy.  Duke & Daisy have a girl, Cindy.  Unfortunately, each of the women die in childbirth, leaving their husbands to remarry four other (unrelated) women, and they have more children.

Comment: Don & Daphne have a boy, Calvin.  Dan & Destiny have a boy, Cuthbert.  David & Danielle have a girl, Candy.  Duke & full-blood Cherokee Dances-With-Elk have a girl, Cinnamon.  Here we have now a group of 8 people, who can constitute the grandparents.  While four of the pairings are half-siblings, those can be avoided.  So, we start with a pool of 12 individuals.  Correct, 4 of them contributed twice, but if we just count the individuals, this is how it COULD work.

Comment: Ahahahah that _stronger statement_ rocks! ;)

Comment: Looks like you forgot about time travel, it was *so* obvious...

Answer (score 27):

**Answer:**

Base 2 numbers! If someone is $a$ of race A ($a\in[0,1]$) and someone else is $b\in[0,1]$ race A, their offspring is $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)=\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b$.

This immediately screams "base 2" because you'll get this recursive half pattern.

So let's write something in base 2, take `101` this is 1/2+1/8 (there's a 0 in the 1/4 column) which is 5/8ths as binary, we halve it, which in base 2 is just shifting everything right once, to get `0101` and then add it with the other parent (after shifting theirs).

For example: `1`x`0` (where `x` means "have baby with") is `01+00=01`=0.5.

The operation of `x` is closed with finite binary strings - which I will call "race strings".

Adding two terminating numbers is a terminating number.

That means this is closed. It's like the integers in the real numbers, using adding you cannot escape the integers, from inside them. Same sort of closure.

To be 1/3rd is not a finite race-string, so cannot have come from two finite race strings. QED.

---

**Here's how I got to the answer**

It could be a fraction so close to 1/12 it's easier to say 1/12 than say "21/256ths"

Lets take "race A", if someone who is x/y race A and someone who is a/b of race A, their offspring is $0.5\frac{x}{y} + 0.5\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b})$

But $\frac{x}{y}$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ must also come from this relation.

Now 1/3 (1/12 = 1/4 * 1/3) is a recurring number expressed in base 2 (in base 10 it goes 0.1s then 0.01s, then 0.001s and so forth, in base 2 it goes 1/2, 1/4, 1/8...)

So say we wanted someone who was 1/2 + 1/8 of race A, that'd be "101" in binary in this form, it terminates, the 3/4 used in the comments, that's "110" it terminates.

Remember the relation above, if someone is "0110" (3/8) and someone else is "1100" (3/4) say, we get the result by shifting one right and adding, in this case

```
 "00110"   
+"01100" which is "01001" or 9/32,
```

So to be 1/12th would mean someone who was a quarter, and someone who is a third, but as you can see no one can be a third (in finite steps) starting from 1 or 0 of race A

To sum up! To be 1/3rd something (an infinite string of 0s and 1s) you can't have come from the "product" of two people who have finite strings representing their race. We've seen that "finite strings" are closed (2 people of finite-race string produce someone of finite race string) and thus can't have been produced by two people of finite strings.

Comment: On the other hand, if 1/12th is an _estimate_, he could be 11/128th Cherokee, which is within 4% of 1/12th.  or 21/256 is within 3%, 43/512 is within 1%...

Comment: I used 21/256ths but whatever

Comment: "To be 1/3rd is not a finite race-string, so cannot have come from two finite race strings" - if there are multiple potential fathers with a chance for each of them to be the real father, you can kind of get 1/3rd. :P

Comment: There are other ways of reaching ${ 1 \over 3}$: http://www.bbc.com/news/health-31594856.

Answer (score 14):

You can get as close as you like to any fraction. For example, you can be between 1 / 12.5 and 1 / 11.5 Cherokee, and then claiming "I'm one 12th Cherokee" in every day language would be correct.

Also, the fractions that we usually use are approximations. If one parent is pure white and one parent is pure black, the child isn't half white and half black. It will be statistically close to 1/2 each, but in reality the genes are not taken exactly half from each parent, so that child will be a bit more in one of the two directions and not exactly in the middle.

Comment: Actually, children are genetically exactly 50% related to their parents, barring genetic problems.  For chromosome 1, each parent contributes exactly one copy, and the kid has two, one from each parent.  Recombination may occur, but since both chromosomes are from the same parent, genetic contribution is always 50/50.  Percentages can be mixed up at the grandparent-grandchild level, though.

Comment: Makes sense to me.  I've always told people I'm 1/3rd French: one grandparent + one great-great-grandparent.  It's not literally true, but it's close enough.  I guess that'd make my own grandkids 1/12 French, even if the actually number is closer to 1/13 (probably there's some forgotten great-...-great grandparents out there somewhere).

Comment: If only one great grandparent counts as French, then you're exactly 1/8th French.  Your own grandkids will be exactly 1/32nd French, assuming no other French descendancy enters the tree.  The grandparent doesn't add anything.  If you count the grandparent as full French, then those fractions become 1/4th and 1/16th respectively.

Comment: @MooingDuck If the grandparent is full French and _another_ great-grandparent is full French, that means you have 1/4 from the grandparent and 1/8 from great-grandparent for 3/8 French. However, in his case, it's a great-*great*-grandparent, so it's $1/16+4/16=5/16$ French, which is close enough to a third.

Comment: @cpast: I had assumed that the grandparent was a descendant of the great-grandparent, but I realize now that this was not necessary a correct assumption, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6):

In a "continuous inheritance" model, no, because of the answers above.

In a naive chromosomal model, no, because 46 is not divisible by 12.

In a model which includes recombination, yes.  Recombination (aka crossing over) between the parent's chromosomes results in a new chromosome type which has parts from one grandparent and parts from the other (usually one section from each).  It is frequent and random enough that people by heritage 1/8th Cherokee would actually have a pretty big variation in their amount of genetic relatedness to their one 100% Cherokee g-grandparent.  The diagrams here illustrate actual inheritance of one grandparent's genes: http://www.dnainheritance.kahikatea.net/autosomal.html - which shows that the variation in relatedness to a particular grandparent is huge.

The way real recombination works is actually pretty complex, though, and not purely random.  Females recombine more than males (it's not just 50% of the time - females are ~45% something percent, males ~35%), and there are recombination hotspots which are locations which "prefer" to be the site of a cross somehow.  Plus, there is lots of other selection going on even after fertilization.  But these don't make it impossible to be 1/12, since they probably aren't monitoring the whole genotype.

On the actual "active gene" level, though, while you can do it, it may not mean much (since naively in terms of genes only, we are already extremely closely related to all other humans) It would make more sense to look for people who are 1/12 of the way genetically between two groups.  i.e. take a Cherokee variant for 1/12 of all the genes which are not fixed in either Cherokee or the target group (being careful to spread them out).  If you did the selection in a way which locally (within one chromosome) obeyed a plausible recombination history, this would be indistinguishable from somehow who just got lucky to be exactly 1/12 Cherokee.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that we define your heritage as 1/2 (father + mother), then it is not possible to come up with exactly 1/12. Assuming we start with people who are full Cherokee or not Cherokee at all, i.e. 0 or 1, then all their descendants are going to be some integer over a power of 2. A power of 2 can never reduce to 12, as 12 is a multiple of 3 and a power of 2 can never be a multiple of 3.

That said, someone could conceivably be a fraction that rounds to something close to 1/12. For example, suppose a Cherokee marries a non-Cherokee. The result is 1/2 Cherokee. This person marries a full Cherokee, result 3/4. Marries non, result 3/8. Marries full, result 11/16. Marries non, result 11/32. Marries non, result 11/64. Marries non, result 11/64. Marries non, result 11/128. That's pretty close to 1/12.

But THAT said, to come up with a number that is even approximately 1/12 you have to have detailed knowledge of your heritage with many inter-marriages going back at least 6 or 7 generations, and few people would have that much detail. So if you were (approximately) 1/12 Cherokee, I'd guess you wouldn't know it.

Years ago I helped develop a computer system for an Indian reservation, and they measured "bloodedness" in 8ths, which requires knowing your ancestry for 3 generations. They didn't cut it any finer than that.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer.  Despite the incorrectness of other answers because of certain assumptions, that the Indian tribes themselves don't go any less than a 1/8th means that any self-described 1/12th Cherokee has some likelihood of being incorrect.

Comment: @Random no, I'm asking on Math.SE because I'm interested in the mathematics of it, not hand-waving approximations.

Comment: As I said above, mathematically it's not possible to be exactly 1/12 Cherokee. You could be approximately 1/12, but exactly? No. The denominator of the fraction has to be a power of 2, and 12 is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you define being Cherokee.

As others have shown, no possible **normal** breeding sequence can produce someone who is 1/12th.

However, we now have three-parent children (26 chromosomes from a male, 26 chromosomes from a female, an ovum with only the mitochondrial DNA from another female.)  If one of those three parents is 1/4th Cherokee you could call the child 1/12th Cherokee.

Answer (score 3):

Genealogy and ancestry is fun. My sister did one of those DNA tests that places your geographic location genetically. Here are her results:

30% Great Britain, 
29% Scandinavia, 
20% Ireland, 
8% Europe West, 
6% Finland/NW Russia, 
4% Europe East, 
3% Iberian Peninsula.

Obviously, those don't fit nicely into the 1/(2^x) model. Part of this is because they are larger region (Scandinavia covers multiple countries for example). Another part of this is the fact that, genetically, these regions are similar enough to have some crossovers.

Comment: This is anecdotal, not really an answer, and doesn't actually speak to any of the OP's (mathematical) questions. (e.g., '30% Great Britain' could easily mean 5/16ths Great British up to some rounding error).

Comment: I would accept the idea that 30% GB is due to some rounding error if the values didn't total 100% together and the error was less than 1% offf (5/16 is 31.25%). As I stated at the end, a large amount of genealogical errors come from crossover between regions. This question is as much sociological as it is mathematical and that blurs the perfect nature of the science.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically you can't. Let $a$ and $b$ mark the number of generations since the last time each of your parents had exactly one 100% Cherokee ancestor. Let's assume that

$\frac{\frac{1}{2^a} + \frac{1}{2^b}}{2} = \frac{1}{12}$

$\frac{1}{2^a} + \frac{1}{2^b} = \frac{1}{6}$

$\frac{6}{2^a} + \frac{6}{2^b} = 1$

From now on, just for the sake of simplicity, let's presume $a > b$.

$6 + 6*2^{a - b} = 2^a$

$3 + 3*2^{a - b} = 2^{a - 1}$

$2^{a - 1} - 3*2^{a - b} = 3$

This last equation is true if you manage to find two different powers of 2 (both even numbers), either one a multiple of 3 (it's still even), whose difference is an odd number. You won't find one, we have a contradiction.

But as stated, this is a mathematical statement. Genetics work quite different.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to count *genetics*. Suppose that 120 years ago all four pairs of your mother's great grand parents (8 in all) were pregnant with their first child, and both pairs of your father's grandparents (4 in all) were pregnant with their first child.

Thus at that moment in time you have 12 ancestors, of mixed generations back, just entering child-bearing years.

If exactly one of those twelve ancestors is full-blooded Cherokee, and the other eleven have no Cherokee blood, then:

**Yes, you are clearly 1/12th Cherokee.**

Whether you are counting back in even generations or in even years is an arbitrary choice, and it is incorrect to state that only one makes sense. Perhaps there are other valid ways to count ancestry back that would enable other fractions and counting.

Comment: Unfortunately this clever solution does not work. Go back another generation on the father's side. There are eight people, and by assumption, six of them are 0% Cherokee and two of them are 100% Cherokee. Now there are sixteen total ancestors in that generation and two are Cherokee, so you are 1/8th Cherokee, not 1/12th.

Comment: @EricLippert: It depends on whether you are counting backwards to a point in time, or to a number of generations. For many people it makes more sense to count backwards to a point in time, for which this means of counting makes sense. As others have pointed out, **all** methods of counting ancestry are approximations at best since 99% of all our genes are identical across the entire human race.

Comment: When calculating ancestry portions, I find it most natural that half of my ancestry comes from my mother and the other half from my father. If you take this starting point with "pure" ancestors a couple of generations back (full Cherokee or fully non-Cherokee), you can only get numbers of the form $a/2^b$. Your model seems to make your ancestry percentages dependent on the time of history you compare yourself to (the moment when you had 12 ancestors alive in your example).

Comment: I agree with Joonas -- this characterization doesn't make a lot of sense to me. With this characterization, I could be 1/12 Cherokee one day and some completely different fraction the next, and some completely different fraction the next, and so on. What sense does it make to say "I was 1/12th Cherokee on August 1st 1830, but 2/25ths Cherokee on August 2nd 1830"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that strictly from a statistical-genetic perspective, the most we can do is to compare genes and give a probabilistic value of somebody belonging to a certain genetic pool. Just consider mutations and any inter-race breeding that has happened during milleniums to highlight the fuzziness of the notion of defining somebody's race in any exact quantifiable terms. In addition, the notion of being *exactly* `1/2` Cherokee from statistical-genetic perspective does not make sense since the distribution of genes is not 50%:50% as very insightfully pointed out in the comments by @SteveJessop. There seems to be no mathematically sensical way to say somebody is 100% or 0% Cherokee, even less `1/n` Cherokees for any choice of integer value `n > 1`, by just looking at their genetic markup.

Thus I would say the definition of being a proud member of Cherokee is a matter of social and personal identification. This definition is gray, but at least it gives us sample members of Human Race that we can meaningfully call fully Cherokee or totally not being a Cherokee (while ignoring the grey area cases), which validates the use of fractions in defining somebody's degree of "Cherokeeness".

After thus laying foundational definitions, we refer to the curious cases of children with three parents  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-parent_baby:

> Three-parent babies are human offspring with three genetic parents, created through a 
>   specialized form of In vitro fertilisation in which the future baby's mitochondrial DNA
>   comes from a third party.

See also http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-28986843 for the young case of Mrs. Saarinen.

Such a child would have DNA from three people, and in a sense have three genetic parents. Let's assume one of the parents of such a child would be a Cherokee and two others "totally not Cherokees", and furthermore to make the case stronger, let's assume all three genetic parents would also participate in the upbringing and support of the child so that there really would be three parents in the strongest imaginable and possible sense. We could argue (though not with any mathematical rigor) that the resulting offspring would be 1/3 Cherokee. Now if she or he would produce an offspring, it would make some sense (even if not mathematically very rigorous) to say that offspring would be 1/6 Cherokee. Paring 1/6 Cherokee with non-Cherokee parent would give us an offspring that might want to call himself/herself 1/12 Cherokee.

Logically speaking, though, the mentioned case cannot be 1/12 Cherokee by this avenue because this controversial treatment option has not been in existence long enough for any such three parent child to have a grandchild.

Comment: If the DNA comes from three parents, does it come in equal parts? And how much of all DNA is mitochondrial DNA, if we want to include it in our model?

Comment: We should probably ask this in biology SE. As I mentioned, this all is rather loose-minded mathematical reasoning and reduces the complexity of genetics (I was asking the same question as you did in my mind).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: it's a small proportion, and it's not generally included in calculations of what proportion Cherokee someone is. If it were, then someone with a full-Cherokee mother and a not-at-all-Cherokee father would be slightly more than half Cherokee (and 2/3 Cherokee by the counter-factual assumption in this question of even distribution of DNA), since in the usual case we get all mitochondrial DNA and half nuclear DNA from our mother and half nuclear DNA from our father.

Comment: It seems to me also that the question is non-sensical when attempted to be viewed with any mathematical rigour (unless we want to resort to obscurely ridiculous definitions). The simplistic talk of fractional Cherokeeness kind of implies the notion of somebody being 100% Cherokee and somebody 0% Cherokee in genetical sense which does not make any factual sense. The suggestion per comment on the question of  somebody spending 1 month per year as Cherokee is the only definition of "1/12 Cherokee" that makes sense to me and that has nothing to do with genetics.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for the insightful comment. I rewrote the answer to appear more rigorous, using social identity as the definition of one's "Cherokeeness" as there is obviously no genetical/statistical way to say somebody is 100% Cherokee.

Comment: About your last comment, it still could be one of the 3 parents is already 1/4 cherokee.

Comment: @FlorianF - Then just choose different parent to get this thought game working, one whose ancestors did not consider themselves to be Cherokees. The whole stupid question that I regret answering in the first place was about how could it be possible to have such fractional Cherokee ancestry. Sorry if my explanation was not robust enough. I have edited the answer for improved clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Not without inbreeding.
If we assume not shared ancestry paths, then each generation you go back you double the number of ancestors, thus 2^n where n is the generation.
taking the previous 95 generations and dividing each by 12 reveals that there are no members of (this part) of the series that are divisible by 12. Interestingly, all moduli are alternately 4 or 8.
While this is not a complete mathematical proof, beyond a few generations it is hard to determine race with much certainty anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this answer brings something new that is not in the other answers already? (It might just be that I'm slow, but I don't see it.)

Comment: I was noting that inbreeding might make it possible, not something I spotted in other comments (though maybe I missed it). Also I took a different approach to the answer as my mathematic skills are not as good as others and I thought the recurrent modulus of the series was interesting. Worth a downvote? sorry you thought so!

Comment: @Blake The problem with this answer (I didn't downvote it, but I didn't upvote either despite the passing note about inbreeding) is that everything _but_ the (almost empty) first sentence **has** already been said by someone else, and by and large said better elsewhere (there are very straightforward mathematical proofs that don't need 95 generations of evidence - you could even have proven your 'alternately 4 or 8' with a quick pair of multiplications!).